# Guardar ID de usuario en todos los fragments de una app?

Tags: android-studio, activity, fragment

Tengo un fragment login, un fragment para registrar clientes y dependiendo de quién ingrese en el login recogeremos un ID distinto por cada usuario ingresado.

En una respuesta a esta pregunta me recomendaron crear una clase con un par de métodos get y set para hacer una variable que permanezca durante todo el ciclo de vida de la app, sin embargo me salta este error cuando intento pasar la ID con el método set. Dejo los códigos por aquí y el mensaje de error.

///ERROR///

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.usuario.alfapharmashop, PID: 6207
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.usuario.alfapharmashop.Adapters.Constants.setIdUsuario(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.usuario.alfapharmashop.Fragments.LoginFragment.onResponse(LoginFragment.java:233)
    at com.example.usuario.alfapharmashop.Fragments.LoginFragment.onResponse(LoginFragment.java:41)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

///Clase Constants///

```
public class Constants {

public static int id_usuario;

public  void setIdUsuario(int id)
{
    this.id_usuario = id;
}

public int getIdUsuario()
{
    return this.id_usuario;
}
```

}

///Fragment Login///

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private TextView textoInfo;
private TextView textorespuesta;
private TextView resultado;
private EditText editUsuario;
private EditText editContra;
private Button botonEntrar;
private IComunicaFragments logginFragments;
private Constants constants;
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

ProgressDialog dialog;
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment LoginFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static LoginFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    textoInfo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtRespuesta1);
    textorespuesta = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtRespuesta2);
    resultado = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.resultado);
    editUsuario = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.username);
    editContra = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.password);
    botonEntrar = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    logginFragments.setLogginDrawable(false);

    botonEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String usuario = editUsuario.getText().toString();
            String contra= editContra.getText().toString();
            iniciarSesion(usuario,contra);
        }
    });

   /* String defaultSharedPreferencesName = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && false) {
        defaultSharedPreferencesName = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(getContext());
    }else {
        defaultSharedPreferencesName = getActivity().getPackageName() + "_preferences";
    }*/

    sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("usuario",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String prefStringUser = sharedPref.getString("user", "");
    String prefStringPass = sharedPref.getString("pass", "");
    if (!prefStringUser.isEmpty() && !prefStringPass.isEmpty()) {
        editUsuario.setText(prefStringUser);
        editContra.setText(prefStringPass);
    }

    return vista;
}


private void iniciarSesion(String user, String pass) {

    dialog=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    dialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesión...");
    dialog.incrementProgressBy(100);
    dialog.show();

    String url="https://alfapharma.000webhostapp.com/loginUsuarios.php?usuario="+user+"&contrasena="+pass;

    jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
    // request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        logginFragments = (IComunicaFragments) getActivity();

    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    dialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"El servidor no está disponible, intentalo de nuevo más tarde."+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("ERROR",error.toString());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    dialog.hide();

    //    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Mensaje: "+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("agente");
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;

    Agente agente = new Agente();
    try {
        jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(0);

            agente.setId(jsonObject.optInt("id"));
            agente.setUsuario(jsonObject.optString("usuario"));
            agente.setContrasena(jsonObject.optString("contrasena"));
            agente.setTipo(jsonObject.optInt("tipo"));


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        //Get Editor object
        sharedPref.edit().putString("user", agente.getUsuario());
        sharedPref.edit().putString("pass", agente.getContrasena());
        //sp.edit().commit(); //Blocking Operation
        sharedPref.edit().apply(); //Asynchronous



        textoInfo.setText("Bienvenido " + agente.getUsuario());

        Log.e("ID AGENTE",agente.getId()+"");
        textorespuesta.setText("Has iniciado sesión correctamente.");
        resultado.setText("Ya puedes acceder al menú.");
        textorespuesta.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        editUsuario.setEnabled(false);
        editContra.setEnabled(false);
        botonEntrar.setEnabled(false);

        editUsuario.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        editContra.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        botonEntrar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        logginFragments.setLogginDrawable(true);
        constants.setIdUsuario(agente.getId());




}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}}
```

///Fragment Registrar///

```
public class RegistroClienteFragment extends Fragment implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private TextView razonSocial;
private TextView CIF;
private TextView dirFiscal;
private TextView dirPostal;
private TextView poblacion;
private TextView codigoPostal;
private TextView pais;
private TextView telefono;
private TextView fax;
private TextView mail;
private TextView web;
private Spinner formaPago;
private TextView personaResponsable;
private TextView nombreBanco;
private TextView poblacionBanco;
private TextView IBAN;
private TextView SWIFT;
private Button btnRegistrar;
private Constants constants;
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

ProgressDialog dialog;

// RequestQueue request;
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public RegistroClienteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment PerfilFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static RegistroClienteFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    RegistroClienteFragment fragment = new RegistroClienteFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registro_cliente, container, false);

    razonSocial = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditRazSoc);
    CIF = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditCIF);
    dirFiscal= (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditDirFis);
    dirPostal = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditDirPos);
    poblacion = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditPob);
    codigoPostal = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditCP);
    pais = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditPais);
    telefono = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditTlf);
    fax = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditFax);
    mail = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditMail);
    web = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditWeb);
    formaPago = (Spinner) vista.findViewById(R.id.spinnerFormaPago);

    personaResponsable = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditPersResp);
    nombreBanco = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditNomEnt);
    poblacionBanco = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditPobBan);
    IBAN = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditIBAN);
    SWIFT = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtEditSWIFT);

    btnRegistrar = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrar);

    String[] opciones = {"Pago contado","Giro 15 días","Giro 30 días","Giro 60 días"};
    formaPago.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, opciones));



    btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("ID AGENTE", constants.getIdUsuario()+"");

            insertarCliente();
        }
    });
    return vista;
}

public void insertarCliente(){
    dialog=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    dialog.setMessage("Registrando cliente...");
    dialog.incrementProgressBy(100);
    dialog.show();

    String url="https://alfapharma.000webhostapp.com/registroCliente.php?razonsocial="+razonSocial.getText().toString()
            +"&cif="+CIF.getText().toString()
            +"&dirfiscal="+dirFiscal.getText().toString()
            +"&dirpostal="+dirPostal.getText().toString()
            +"&poblacion="+poblacion.getText().toString()
            +"&codigopostal="+Integer.parseInt(codigoPostal.getText().toString())
            +"&pais="+pais.getText().toString()
            +"&telefono="+Integer.parseInt(telefono.getText().toString())
            +"&fax="+Integer.parseInt(fax.getText().toString())
            +"&mail="+mail.getText().toString()
            +"&web="+web.getText().toString()
            +"&reqfact="+formaPago.getSelectedItem().toString()
            +"&personaresponsable="+personaResponsable.getText().toString()
            +"&nombreentidad="+nombreBanco.getText().toString()
            +"&poblacionbanco="+poblacionBanco.getText().toString()
            +"&iban="+IBAN.getText().toString()
            +"&swift="+SWIFT.getText().toString()
            +"&idagente="+constants.getIdUsuario();

    url = url.replace(" ","%20");

    jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
    // request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

}
// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    dialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"El servidor no está disponible, intentalo de nuevo más tarde."+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("ERROR",error.toString());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    dialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"REGISTRO OKEY."+response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cliente registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma de recoger ese ID y utilizarlo en cualquier fragment de la app como si fuera una cariable global o algo parecido? Estoy usando Volley para recoger los datos de una BD externa y no tengo problemas para obtener el ID pero cuando intento pasar el dato a otro fragment (utilice bundle) me devuelve 0 en cualquier caso

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido a SOes. Sí, es necesario, edita tu pregunta y agrega todo el código que tienes. Revisa el tour: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso lee cómo preguntar aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: He conseguido resolverlo, era una tontería! Se me olvidó poner los métodos de la clase Constants como staticos (aunque tuve que quitar el "this" que me tiraba error) Muchas gracias a Iñigo por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es guardar el valor de una variable mientras la aplicación está en uso, te recomiendo que utilices una clase con la que puedas guardar y recuperar ese valor.

He aquí un ejemplo:

```
public class Constants {

    public static String id_usuario= "";

    public static void setIdUsuario(String id)
    {
        this.id_usuario = id;
    }

    public static void getIdUsuario()
    {
        return this.id_usuario;
    }
}
```

Para interactuar con está variable sólo tendrías que hacerles la llamada:

```
Constants.setIdUsuario(1);
Constants.getIdUsuario();
```

En caso de que necesites guardar la id aunque la app se cierre, te recomiendo usar el `SharedPreferences` de `Android Studio`.

```
//Para guardar un dato.
SharedPreferences datos_usuario= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("id_usuario",1);
editor.putString("nombre_usuario","MiNombre");
editor.apply();

//Para obtener los datos
SharedPreferences datos_usuario= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Integer id_usuario= datos_usuario.getInt("id_usuario", -1);
String name = datos_usuario.getString("nombre_usuario", "");
```